# Binary Search Tree with multiple child and two nodes pointing left and right

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to make a binary tree like this as given in the image given below in C programming language.

Structure to make binary tree having two nodes is this -

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
```

But for making a tree with multiple childs, structure needs to change every time, so is there any way to make a structure that changes every time?

[image]

Comment: A binary tree, by definition, has a maximum of two direct children per node.  What you're describing in your picture isn't a binary tree.  Perhaps you're thinking of a B-Tree?

Comment: There are a number of ways to represent a tree with multiple children per node.  If you can set a small limit to the number of children a node can have, then a small fixed array for the children will suffice.  If it is unbounded, then you could dynamically adjust the sizes of the child arrays.  Or you could use another structure, such as a doubly-linked list.  It all depends on your usage patterns.

Comment: Instead of `struct node* left;` and right, you can make a list of child nodes. In that way the number of child nodes is not limited.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a node like this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *firstChild;
    node *nextSibling;
};
```

And then,

1. First child is accessed this way: **myNode->firstChild**
2. Second child: **myNode->firstChild->nextSibling**
3. Nth child: **myNode->firstChild->nextSibling->...->nextSibling**

This will involve null checks and iteration when going through child nodes.

Comment: That's called a [Left child right sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree)

Answer (score 1):

In C, you cannot make a structure change dynamically. But what you want (variable number of children in each node) can be achieved in a slightly roundabout way. If you want to preserve the left and right nodes as separate entities from the other children, you could have a binary tree that contains a linked list for all additional children of that node:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int data;
    ChildNode *firstChild;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
};

struct ChildNode
{
    int data;
    ChildNode *next;
};
```